# Updating in relational algebra

Tags: relational-algebra

Consider a relation `Human(name, age, height, weight)`. To update an attribute, e.g. age for the whole relation, I can write `Human <- π name,age*2,height,weight (Human)`. But what if I want to update just some specific tuple? From SQL: `UPDATE Human SET age = 20 WHERE name = "John"`. Where do I put sigma/σ (restriction/selection)?

Comment: Most variants of "relational algebra" (as if there were only one) don't have a PROJECT with the SQL-like functionality of yours that goes beyond dropping columns. So if you are mapping to "relational algebra" make sure you find out what that means re your assignment.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `σ/RESTRICT/SELECT`-chosen tuple(s) to be modified via `MINUS/-`, then `UNION/U` the modified tuple(s) in.

```
Human <-
        (Human - σ name="John" (Human))
    U   π name,20,height,weight (σ name="John" (Human))
```

Assignment isn't a relational algebra operator, it is a programming language operator. Your notation isn't nested calls to relational algebra operators, it is a programming language with some expressions that are nested calls to relational operators. Each relational operator produces a value transformed from input values. Assignment sets a variable to a value. There's no particular connection between projection and assignment. Here the projection happens to not be the last operator used to determine the value to be assigned.